# Meet some problems when using fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

This is my first time to use "scipy.optimization".
I define a simple function and want to minimize it.

```
def func(x,*args):
    t = 0
    x[0] += args[0]
    x[1] += args[1]
    t += (x[0]-x[1])**2
    return t

def fprime(x,*args):
    a = numpy.zeros(2)
    a[0] = 2*(x[0]-x[1]-1)
    a[1] = 2*(x[1]-x[0]+1)
    return a

if __name__=='__main__':
    constant = numpy.array([1,2])
    initial_value = 1.2, 1.3
    bounds = [(-2.0,2.0), (-2.0,2.0) ]
    best, val, d =    optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func,x0=initial_value,fprime=fprime,args=constant,bounds=bounds)
    print 'Position of the minimum',best, 'and its value',val
```

But when I run it, it returns me some errors:

```
File "D:/Code/Python/LFC/dataset.py", line 8, in func
x[0] += args[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I try to debug it, then I found:
   when it runs into the 'func' first time, the 'args' has values,
   but when it runs into 'func' second time, the 'args' has no values,
so it returns a IndexError.

I don't know why this happen? I would be very grateful if anyone who can help me.

-------------------------------------------------------------lines----------------------------------------------------------------
I found args should be tuple, so I change 'constant' to '(constant,)' and it does not return error.
But the output of this code is :

```
Position of the minimum [ 5.2         6.71477239] and its value 2.29453538085
```

Why the 'bounds' didn't work?
I think the minimum of function '(x0-x1-1)^2' is 0 but why the output is 2.29453538085?

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify the input array:

```
def func(x,*args):
    t = 0
    x[0] += args[0]
    x[1] += args[1]
```

Should be

```
    x = [x[0] + args[0], x[1] + args[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't understand.  Why your code not equal to my code?   'x = [x[0] + args[0], x[1] + args[1]]' also change the input array x, isn't it?

Comment: It does not --- you may want to think in more depth what variables actually mean in Python: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/ --- it works similarly as in Javascript, but differently from C/C++/Fortran.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. I have a new problem: My data set is very big and the computation is very slow. How can I know which stage we're on during the optimization procedure? print something in the block of 'fucn' or in the block of 'fprime'?  There are other ways? Thanks again!